# Set execute bit for a file using python

Tags: python, macos, file-io

Using python on Mac OS, I would like to open a file for writing and put some shell commands into it. Later to be run in terminal.

```
with open("my_script.sh", "w") as fd:
    fd.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
    fd.write("echo $PATH\n")
```

This will create the file, but I could not figure how to set the execute bit so when I run it in the Terminal I will not get:

```
sh: my_script.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Use subprocess to set proper permissions to the file -  http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @theharshest: How would you do that with `subprocess`? (I suppose you could `check_call(['chmod', 'a+x', 'myscript.sh'])`, in the same way that you can `check_call(['echo', 'foo'])` instead of `print('foo')` if you really want to, but… why?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import os
os.chmod("my_script.sh", 0744)
```

Pick the value properly though. Some values might not be safe.

Comment: You need to use `0o744` for Python 3 compatibility.

Answer (score 14):

You can always do this from the Terminal shell, before running it, using [`chmod`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/):

```
chmod a+x my_script.sh
```

If you want to do it from Python, you can use either [`chmod`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chmod) or [`fchmod`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fchmod) in the `os` module. Since you've already got the file open, I'd do the latter:

```
with open("my_script.sh", "w") as fd:
    fd.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
    fd.write("echo $PATH\n")
    os.fchmod(fd.fileno(), stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IXOTH)
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, there's no direct equivalent to `chmod a+x` adding the `x` flag for everyone while leaving everything else alone. But you can do the same thing the `chmod` command-line tool actually does: [`stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) the file (or, in this case, [`fstat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fstat)) to get the existing permissions, then modify them:

```
with open("my_script.sh", "w") as fd:
    fd.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
    fd.write("echo $PATH\n")
    mode = os.fstat(fd.fileno()).st_mode
    mode |= stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH
    os.fchmod(fd.fileno(), stat.S_IMODE(mode))
```

(You don't actually need the `S_IMODE` step on most platforms, because either `st_mode` doesn't have any extra bits, or (f)`chmod` harmlessly ignores them—as OS X does. But it's better to do the right thing, to make your code portable and future-proof.)

Most people consider "friendly" names like `S_IXUSR` to be not particularly friendly, and once you learn to think of modes in octal terms it's actually easier than trying to remember how POSIX abbreviates things, so you may prefer this:

```
with open("my_script.sh", "w") as fd:
    fd.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
    fd.write("echo $PATH\n")
    mode = os.fstat(fd.fileno()).st_mode
    mode |= 0o111
    os.fchmod(fd.fileno(), mode & 0o7777)
```

The `111` means executable by user, group, and other (the same thing as that `|` of the various `ST_IX*` bits), and `7777` is all bits you're allowed to pass to (f)`chmod` (the same thing that `S_IMODE` does).